# need help on php require

Tags: php

What do I need to put in a php code so that the user cannot access it even if he specified the correct url for the page they are trying to access. And redirect it to the logon page. I'm really having difficulty in this matter, everytime I click back button on the browser the user can still access the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you require/include your from within any other php file like an index.php, then, you can define a constant which will be checked against in your required file.

index.php:

```
define(APP_LOADED, true);
```

required_file.php:

```
if ( !defined(APP_LOADED) ) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit 0;
}
// do something else here
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a full-blown login system.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement some kind of ACL check. Basic solution would be to set [SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) upon logging in.

If user accesses some page he shouldn't see, you just redirect him back to login page.

```
if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ "login" ] && ... ) {
    header( "Location: path_to_login_page" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (...) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
    exit 0;
}
```

Just make a proper if clause.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

PS: Ty Michael

Comment: You probably want an `exit;` after the `header()` call, or the rest of the script will still get executed